Weird 70s movie where people go mad
Trying to get the name of a very weird movie I saw as a kid, which I assume was made in the 70s. It was about a cult and everyone was trapped in the area they lived (possibly by some invisible force although I don't quite remember) and I recall an outdoor scene of a person/people trying to escape but not making it. 
There was a lot of singing/humming and that was what the cult members used to send the main character insane at the end. I assume they were all mad too. 
Sorry so vague. 
I suspect it might have been a British movie and it's the sort of thing you could imagine Peter O'Toole being in, although I don't think he was!

In the Mouth of Madness?

No too recent and very set based. This was a lot of outdoors scenes.

Could use some more specifics. How were the people dressed?  What time period was the movie set? British accents? Were any UFOs  referenced? How about white robes?  I have a couple of films in mind, but need more information.

I'm struggling to remember clothing but based on the subject matter I would imagine they would be in robes yes and it was a modern time period although I don't think there was anything that gave away exactly when. I don't recall any UFO references. I think when the guy tried to escape the cult members somehow got into his head with their singing/humming and it was too painful for him to continue. I believe they were British accents.

Original The Wicker Man, not Nicolas Cage remake.

A police sergeant is sent to a Scottish island village in search of a missing girl whom the townsfolk claim never existed. Stranger still are the rites that take place there. - IMDb


You might want to elaborate in which way this fits the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.
